# I can't get the input box value

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to build an script that when the user scrolldown, it shows more results.

I inserted into an array with some values, and i inserted an if statement, that counts the number of values that are permited per page.

```
<?php
    $arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20);
        $i = 0;

        $more = 1;
        foreach ($arr as $value) {

        echo $value;
        echo '<br>';
          if(++$i > $more*9) break;


    }
```

?>

I created an hidden input, it has the 1 value.

I did that because i want to change the value using JQuery

```
<script>
    $(window).scroll(function () {

        if ($(document).height() <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) {
        //insert +1 to the hidden input value

        }
    });
</script>
```

All code

```
    <style>
    div{ height: 1000px}
    </style>
<div>
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" value="1" name="more" />
</form>
  <?php
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20);
    $i = 0;

    $more = $_POST['more'];
    foreach ($arr as $value) {

    echo $value;
    echo '<br>';
      if(++$i > $more*9) break;


}

  ?>
</div>

    <script>
    $(window).scroll(function () {

        if ($(document).height() <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) {
        alert('<?= $more ?>');

        }
    });
</script>
```

Input

```
  <form method="POST">
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="more" />
</form>
```

But it can't recognize the input hidden.

Comment: Can you please rephrase the `it can't recognize the input hidden` part?

Comment: My english sucks, but the input hidden is not being recognized

Comment: Your code example contains no hidden input element, and no attempt to access a value of an element?

Comment: I meant - which input? and what do you mean by saying "hidden"?

Comment: it contains, but i forgot to put the input hidden there, i'm so sorry, i'm so dumb

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesnt have any `hidden` input type. Hidden input should be like,

```
<input type="hidden" value="1" />
```

Then for incrementing,

```
 $(window).scroll(function () {

     if ($(document).height() <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) {
         $("input[type='hidden']").val(parseInt($("input[type='hidden']").val()) + 1);

     }
 });
```

You should use `parseInt()` because `val()` will return string type.

Answer (score 0):

Before looking at anything at all, the very first thing I would suggest is to look at what the page is loading into iteelf with the post values etc.

The very simplest way to do this is to use a web traffic debugger tool. The one I use for this is Fiddler2, there are many like this, this one is mine (recommendation).

It will mean that you don't need to write any code to look at what the page think's it's doing, you can SEE it from the actual traffic that is that page's request/response instance.

Then if you have something in POST values, is it actually what you expect?
If it is then it's the code that looks at that value, otherwise its the code that generates it..

Hope that helps :)